# Run junit test with on different browsers

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit

I want to run tests on different browsers, using junit, selenium, i have this code:

```
        @Test   //Test1
        public  void logInFaildTest() {
            GridTest gridTest = new GridTest();
            WebDriver webDriver = gridTest.getWebDriver();//get driver 
            LoginPage logIn = new LoginPage(webDriver, url);
            String userName = "user";
            String pass="pass";
             ......................................
            webDriver.close();
        }
        @Test   //Test2 change
        public  void logInFaildTest(WebDriver webDriver ) {
            LoginPage logIn = new LoginPage(webDriver, url);
            String userName = "user";
            String pass="pass";
             ......................................
            webDriver.close();
        }

        @Test //Test3
        public void loginSucsecc(WebDriver webDriver )
        {
            WebDriver webDriver = gridTest.getWebDriver();
            LoginPage logIn = new LoginPage(webDriver, url);
             ......................................
            webDriver.quit();
            assertEquals(expected, actual);
        }
```

In test 1 i create an instance of webdriver inside the test method, in test 2 and 3 i want to get the test driver as parameter and execute the test with the specific webdriver, how can i run test case that can run each function with different web driver(one on firefox other on chrome...).

Answer (score 0):

solution To send test function parameters, must set class as @RunWith(Parameterized.class).
Another solve is to read properties file in each test method, and run the test as the properties.

Answer (score 0):

best way to do is , group the tests which you want to run specific browser.

Send browser parameter from testNg to run in specific browser.

Test Class:

```
    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    @Test(groups="IE")
    public  void logInFaildTest(String browser) {
        GridTest gridTest = new GridTest();
        WebDriver webDriver = gridTest.getWebDriver();//get driver 
        LoginPage logIn = new LoginPage(webDriver, url);
        String userName = "user";
        String pass="pass";
         ......................................
        webDriver.close();
    }
    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    @Test(groups="IE")
    public  void logInFaildTest(String browser ) {
        LoginPage logIn = new LoginPage(webDriver, url);
        String userName = "user";
        String pass="pass";
         ......................................
        webDriver.close();
    }

    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    @Test(groups="Chrome")
    public void loginSucsecc(String browser )
    {
        WebDriver webDriver = gridTest.getWebDriver();
        LoginPage logIn = new LoginPage(webDriver, url);
         ......................................
        webDriver.quit();
        assertEquals(expected, actual);
    }
```

TestNg:

```
<test name="Testing Parameterization">
<parameter name="browser" value="IE"/>
<parameter name="username" value="testuser"/>
<parameter name="password" value="testpassword"/>
    <groups>
        <run>
        <include name="IE"/>
        </run>  
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.parameterization.TestParameters" />
    </classes>
</test>

<test name="Testing Parameterization">
<parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>
<parameter name="username" value="testuser"/>
<parameter name="password" value="testpassword"/>
    <groups>
        <run>
        <include name="chrome"/>
        </run>  
    </groups>
    <classes>
        <class name="com.parameterization.TestParameters" />
    </classes>
</test>
```